# NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Landroid/net/http/HttpsConnection after upgrade to Ubuntu 12

Tags: android

After upgrading my host to Ubuntu 12 and successfully rebuilding android, upon installation on device, the system boot loops into this error:

```
I/Zygote  (  147): Preloading classes...
D/dalvikvm(  147): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47K, 78% free 232K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms
D/dalvikvm(  147): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 73% free 282K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms
D/dalvikvm(  147): GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 70% free 315K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms
D/dalvikvm(  147): GC_EXPLICIT freed 17K, 66% free 353K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms
D/dalvikvm(  147): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 63% free 381K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms
D/dalvikvm(  147): GC_EXPLICIT freed 22K, 58% free 440K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms
W/MediaProfiles(  147): could not find media config xml file
D/dalvikvm(  147): GC_EXPLICIT freed 99K, 47% free 545K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms
W/dalvikvm(  147): Exception Ljava/lang/
NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Landroid/net/http/HttpsConnection;
E/Zygote  (  147): Error preloading android.net.http.HttpsConnection.
E/Zygote  (  147): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/Zygote  (  147):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:181)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadClasses(ZygoteInit.java:297)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/Zygote  (  147): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: algorithm is null
E/Zygote  (  147):     at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.java:77)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl.createDefaultKeyManager(SSLParametersImpl.java:387)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl.getDefaultKeyManager(SSLParametersImpl.java:380)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl.<init>(SSLParametersImpl.java:120)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl.engineInit(SSLContextImpl.java:97)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at android.net.http.HttpsConnection.initializeEngine(HttpsConnection.java:101)
E/Zygote  (  147):     at android.net.http.HttpsConnection.<clinit>(HttpsConnection.java:65)
E/Zygote  (  147):     ... 6 more
E/Zygote  (  147): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
D/AndroidRuntime(  147): Shutting down VM
```

---

The same sources worked fine when built in my Ubuntu 11.10 (64-bit) host.
I did the migration like this:

1) full backup of the aosp source dir, from the 11.10 host

2) setup of a new Ubuntu 12.04 host

3) installation of AOSP pre-requisite packages

4) installation of Oracle jdk 6

5) restore of the aosp source dir (from 1)

The failure in "javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory" suggests some SSL-related issue, but I wonder what I could be missing,...

PS - For additional info on the device and porting project, there's a [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/renesas-emev-osp) hosting discussions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several different trials, looks like I managed to solve this issue.

It all depends on the Java Development Kit used to make the AOSP build. I initially installed the Oracle JDK (as suggested by the android tutorial pages: http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) but then I tried the Open-JDK, which is installed with:

sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk

If you have both Open-JDK and Oracle-JDK installed, you can choose which one to use executing:

sudo update-alternatives --config java
 sudo update-alternatives --config javac
 sudo update-alternatives --config jar
 sudo update-alternatives --config javah
 sudo update-alternatives --config javadoc

and selecting the Open-JDK version for each of these.

The AOSP build using Oracle JDK failed to boot, while the one made with Open-JDK completed the boot just fine.

Hopefully it helps others to solve similar issues.

Comment: When answering your own question, it is standard practice to mark your answer as the accepted answer.